# Splitting Text Paragraph Into Sentences

Tags: python

I'm trying to split up a text file. It comes as a large paragraph. I want to split it up into smaller sentences and have each sentence be a list. From there I can figure out which lists contain a specific word.

This is my code as it currently is:

```
import string

Done = False
while not Done:
    try:
        File = input("Enter your file: ")
        Open_File = open(File, "r")
        Info = Open_File.readline()
        print(Info)
        Open_File.close()
        Done = True
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Sorry that file doesn't exist!")


Info_Str = str(Info)
Info_Str = Info_Str.lower()
Info_Str = Info_Str.replace("'", "")
Info_Str = Info_Str.replace("-", "")
Info_Str = Info_Str.split()
Info_List = Info_Str
Info_List = [''.join(c for c in s if c not in string.punctuation) for s in  Info_List]
New_List = [item for item in Info_List if not item.isdigit()]
for word in New_List[:]:
    if len(word) < 3:
        New_List.remove(word)
print(New_List)
```

If I put in a text file, it only returns the first line of a text file as a list of words.

**How do I have it convert every individual sentence as a separate list of words?** Thanks, in advance.

Comment: What's your exact requirement? If you just want to get the list of words in a file, you can just read all the lines and split using space delimiter.

Comment: I essentially have to find out in which line numbers a specific word appears. Each line is an individual sentence.

Comment: Check my snippet I posted. That should help.

Answer (score 1):

Code you have written is bit big. You can achieve this task in less number of lines of code. Lets first walk how we can achieve it :

1. Open a file using `with` statement. The benefit of `with` statement you don't have to close file explicitly.
2. The paragraph can be split into line using "." or "?".
3. Each line can be split into list using single space.
4. Then, you can search the word you want in that list.

**Code:**

```
#open File
with open("a.txt") as fh:
    for line in fh:
        #Split Paragraph on basis of '.' or ? or !.

        for l in re.split(r"\.|\?|\!",line):
            #Split line into list using space.
            tmp_list = l.split(" ")
            #Search word and if found print that line
            if "Dinesh" in tmp_list:
                print l
```

**NOTE:** My code can be also optimized. I think, since you have just started, this will be good for you.

Comment: I took a whack at this and then I realized: Not all sentences end with periods necessarily (?, !, etc.). I think the original bug that was causing the "it only returns the first line of a text file as a list of words." bug was this line:        `Info = Open_File.readline()`

Comment: In your case, each line is not a line separated by '.'. Suppose I've 

`Hello.new line \n

same line.`

'new line' and 'same line' will be in the different list.

Comment: I tried using 'Info = Open_File.read()' instead but it just returned the whole paragraph as one big list of words instead of splitting it up at each new sentence.

Comment: @JacobIRR - Edited code for splitting paragraph into line using "?" or "!" or any other thing

Answer (score 1):

This will print the sentence number(0 indexing).

```
with open("sample.txt") as f:
    content = f.read() # Read the whole file
    lines = content.split('.') # a list of all sentences
    for num,line in enumerate(lines): # for each sentence
           if 'word' in line:
               print(num)
           else:
               print("Not present")
```