# Need to split the contents of file seperated by mulitple delimiters and display the longest length line

Tags: python

input.txt

```
hi all.i hope all are doing well?
please help with the solution.i tried all the possible solution?
```

Expected o/p:

```
['hi all','i hope all are doing well,
 'please help with the solution','i tried all the possible solution']
```

Comment: what have you tried that didn't work?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: hint; observer the pattern (`.`, `?`). Use `split()`

Comment: would be be better if you'd tell us what did you try

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Splitting Text Paragraph Into Sentences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43315333/splitting-text-paragraph-into-sentences)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tokenize a paragraph into sentence and then into words in NLTK](/questions/37605710/tokenize-a-paragraph-into-sentence-and-then-into-words-in-nltk)

Comment: import re


with open('details') as f:
    data=f.read()
    print(re.split(r'[.?]+',data)

Answer (score 0):

For a quick solution, you can try the following code. But I would suggest you to look into python's re module. Its pretty handy.

```
import re

result = []
pattern = re.compile('[,.?]')

with open('input.txt') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        r = re.split(pattern, line.strip())
        if r:
            result.append(r)


print result
```

Comment: import re


with open('details') as f:
    data=f.read()
    print(re.split(r'[.?]+',data))

    i am getting the below o/p

Comment: ['hi i am sachin', 'how are you', '\ni am good', 'how are you', '']

Comment: input file:hi i am sachin.how are you.
i am good.how are you.

Comment: sorry this is correct input file:hi i am sachin.how are you?
i am good?how are you.

Comment: All these comments must be a part of your original question.

Comment: you can modify that code by using extend instead of append or appending each result checking if the entry is null. Use strip() function on strings to avoid whitespace chars. Read it line by line, not entire file at once.

Answer (score 0):

Another Simple technique for this problem is, Use Split method. I have tried to solve it as simple as possible.

```
file = open("input.txt", "r")
Text = file.read()
Text = Text.replace(".", ",").replace("?", ",")
Text.split(",")
Text = Text[:-1]
```

Comment: When i am running you code same o/p i am getting :['hi i am sachin', 'how are you', '\ni am good', 'how are you', '']

Comment: Expected O/P:['hi i am sachin', 'how are you', 'i am good', 'how are you']

Comment: Yes I got it, that means you will have to remove last element from list && you can use whatever special character and replace it will comma. :)
I am editing the code